# Invert y-axis in barplot

Tags: r

When I do this:

```
barplot(c(1,2,3),ylim=c(4,1))
```

I expect the first bar in the barplot to go from 4 to 1. The second bar should go from 4 to 2 and so on. But that's not what I get. How can I achieve this?

Comment: The first argument to `barplots` is the heights of the bars, not the stopping points (they'll still start at 0, regardless of your axis limits, as far as I know). If you want to draw boxes at arbitrary coordinates as opposed to starting at the x-axis, look into `polygon` or `rect`.

Answer (score 4):

It sounds like you probably want `barplot(c(1,2,3),ylim=c(4,0))`, which yields:

[image]

But it also sounds like you might be asking for (the somewhat confusing) barplot below:

```
barplot(c(3,2,1),ylim=c(0,4), yaxt='n')
axis(2, 0:4, 4:0)
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

In the spirit of Thomas' code, you also might want this:

```
barplot(4 - c(1,2,3),ylim=c(4,0), yaxt='n')
axis(2, 0:4, 4:0)
```

[image]