# How to plot x axis on top and y axis inverted in R Programming?

Tags: r, plot

In general when we do plotting, the plot has the x-axis on bottom (left to right) and y-axis on left (bottom to top).
For example, In R-programming I have a code like this:

```
t <- seq(0,1,0.2)       # need t values in top x axis
plot(t,t^2,type="l")    # need t^2 values in inverted y-axis
```

Now, if we want plot so that the x-axis is on top (left to right) and y-axis inverted (top to bottom).
How can we achieve such a feat in R-programming?
I searched following links in stackoverflow but they could not meet my requirements:
[How to invert the y-axis on a plot](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10360565/how-to-invert-the-y-axis-on-a-plot)

[Invert y-axis in barplot](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21911993/invert-y-axis-in-barplot)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Check out `?axis`

```
t <- seq(0,1,0.2)
plot(t,t,type="l", xaxt = 'n', yaxt = 'n')
lines(t,t^2,col="green")
lines(t,t^3,col="blue")
axis(3)
axis(2, at = pretty(t), labels = rev(pretty(t)))
```

[image]

I'm not sure why the `.0` gets dropped on the y, but you can use `labels = format(rev(pretty(t)), digits = 1)` for consistency

EDIT

to reverse the *entire plot* about one of the axes, just reverse the `xlim` or `ylim` of the plot, and you don't need to worry about flipping or negating your data:

```
t <- seq(0,1,0.2)
plot(t,t,type="l", xaxt = 'n', yaxt = 'n', ylim = rev(range(t)))
lines(t,t^2,col="green")
lines(t,t^3,col="blue")
axis(3)
axis(2, at = pretty(t), labels = format(pretty(t), digits = 1), las = 1)
```

[image]

Comment: If we invert the values of y axis, the curve also should change, (it should change 180 degree, then flip left to right). Here only the values in y-axis are changed, not the curve!!

Comment: @BhishanPoudel you said invert the y-axis, I assumed you only meant the y axis not the whole plot, see edits